# Loading latest firmware iwlwifi-6000

Tags: intel-wireless, firmware

I just installed 11.10 on Dell XPS 15z.
Somebody know why kernel does not load the latest firmware for wifi Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230.

```
$ modinfo iwlagn |grep iwlwifi-6000

firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
```

In package linux-firmware there is latest version (iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode)

```
$ dpkg -L linux-firmware | grep iwlwifi-6000

/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-5.ucode
**/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode**
```

Comment: In 12.04 it works correct:

 $ modinfo iwlwifi |grep iwlwifi-6000

 firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
 firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
 firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode

Answer (score 1):

I did a test with this issue and found following:

- rename firmware usal loaded:

  ```
  mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode_orig
  mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode /lib/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
  ```
- unload/load module

  ```
  sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
  sudo modprobe -v  iwlwifi
  ```
- Look what firmware loaded was found:

  ```
  dmesg | grep iwl | grep firm
  ```

  > [ 4171.852769] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v4, firmware is v6.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have not module "iwlwifi", so I have used "sudo modprobe -r/-v iwlagn". But I still have massage "[ 2789.707813] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.168.5.1 build 33993".