# Update of /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode by simple copy is not working

Tags: 16.04, drivers, intel-wireless, firmware

I have troubles on some wifi networks and the users with the same wifi adapter (Intel 8260), different OS (Fedora), higher version of firmware don't have the problem.

So I try to rename firmware from `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode` to `iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode`

The firmware is available for example in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/LibreELEC/iwlwifi-firmware).

But simply copying it to `/lib/firmware` doesn't work. Seems that there is set a limit to max. number 33:

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware | grep 8000C
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode
```

The rename of /`lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode` to `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode` didn't work, the wifi adapter wasn't able to be used.

Any advice or hints please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading latest firmware iwlwifi-6000](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115427/loading-latest-firmware-iwlwifi-6000)

Comment: Thank you Dave, unfortunatelly the trick doesn't solve the issue. When I rename the file name from version 34 to version 33, the modprobe utility initiates the load of FW, but refuse it during the load with error:      Ah, the information on next lines explains the problem probably:   Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v33, firmware is v34.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please click the Download button here: https://github.com/LibreELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/blob/master/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode

By default, downloads automagically go to the folder Downloads. From the terminal, verify this:

```
cd ~/Downloads
ls | grep 8000C
```

Copy it to /lib/firmware:

```
sudo cp iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Verify that it is there:

```
ls /lib/firmware | grep 8000C
```

In my case, I now see:

```
iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
```

Reboot and tell us what firmware loaded:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

And if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback chilli555, this is in fact the procedure which i did initially. The file iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode is in /lib/firmware, but during reboot the firmware is not loaded, in dmesg i have: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.560484.0 op_mode iwlmvm..... If i rename the file, the modprobe starts to initiate the FW, but it will refuse at the end with the error:   Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v33, firmware is v34.
Maybe the move of limit for v 33 would solve the issue. But i don't know how.

Comment: In almost no case I've ever worked on, renaming firmware or importing firmware outside of what is called for in the driver version, does even the slightest good. I recommend that you start a new question and tell us what the underlying problem is.

Comment: In the script https://github.com/LibreELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/blob/master/synciwl.sh i found the procedure to find maximum version number of firmware for given driver. In linux source code https://git.kernel.org/torvalds/t/linux-${KERNEL}.tar.gz it is in linux-4.13/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/cfg/8000.c the limit : #define IWL8265_UCODE_API_MAX 33       so i deduce that i would need to recompile the modules, or request to increase this nb in the following kernel relases.

Comment: kernel 4.13 has this level 33, kernel 4.14 has the level 34.

Comment: So you could install 18.04 or just tell us what your wireless device is doing/not doing that you are trying to fix.

Comment: In certain networks (in the office) the network the network connection is fluctuating in performance. The time when network is performing well is changed by time (several minutes) when ping to any device is more than 200000 ms or it timeouts. The colleagues having older firmware (Windows, Linux) are suffering by this behavior. Guys who applied newest firmware (34 on Linux, most fresh on Windows) don't experience such issues. It is issue just in this particular network, other wifi networks are fine. I guess there will be loose of physical connectivity between access point and adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to upgrade kernel to 4.15. Kernel 4.13 and lower has limit for highest version of firmware 33, kernel 4.14 is not capable to load the firmware due a [kernel bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1517813). The solution is:

1. [Download the firmware](https://github.com/LibreELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/blob/master/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode) to `/lib/firmware`:

   ```
   wget -O - https://github.com/LibreELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/raw/master/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode |
   sudo tee /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode > /dev/null
   ```
2. [Download the kernel v4.15 and install it](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/01/install-linux-kernel-4-15-in-ubuntu-linux-mint/)
3. reboot OS

Comment: no such firmware files